# Про очередность заполнения базы данных при высокой нагрузке сайта

Tags: highload, веб-программирование, база-данных, очередь

Представим себе такую ситуацию (гипотетическую).  
Пользователи какого-то сайта могут оставлять комментарии на какой-то (фиксированной) странице сайта, и доспустим, что эти комменты сохраняются и нумеруются в базе данных по очереди, т.е. *номер следующего коммента = номер предыдущего + 1*.
Если комментов будет добавляться очень много в единицу времени (много пользователей), то может ли быть такое, что какие-то два коммента будут иметь **один и тот же номер** из-за того, что они пришли на обработку одновременно?

Если такая проблема возможна, то как она решается?  
Celery или Gearman могут решить эту задачу?

Comment: @mipt_ildar, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

> Если такая проблема возможна, то как она решается?

Полем `AUTO_INCREMENT` / `IDENTITY` в БД (в зависимости от того, что за движок используется).

Сам пример - типичная задача на многопоточность, в случае, если этот механизм требуется реализовывать самому, надо осуществлять *lock* ресурса - пока его использует кто-то один, все остальные ждут. Насколько помню, PHP умеет использовать лок чтения файлов - пока один процесс поставил лок на файл, остальные ждут. Насколько понимаю, нормальных способов решения этой проблемы в PHP нет.

Answer (score 0):

Критические секции надо выполнять внутри транзакций. И следите, чтобы не было взаимоблокировок

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?